# Increasing the value of a cell in Google Sheet every (say) 30 days

Tags: google-sheets

I have the starting value of a cell (say A1) as 100 on Jan 1st.

Every month, for a period of 12 months, I need to see the value in A1 increase by 100 i.e. on Feb 1st, March 1st, April 1st...Dec 1st,  A1 should read as 200, 300, 400.. with the final value of 1,200 on Dec 1st.

I'd be grateful for any answers, am stumped.

Comment: Welcome. Please see how to [ask] and edit your question. Also please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Still interested in an answer? Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is a hind. Use a combination of these [Google Sheets functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273): `EOMONTH`,  `TODAY` and `MONTH`.

Answer (score 1):

In A1:

`=(DATEDIF("01/01/2022",TODAY(),"m")+1)*100`

Replace the date (in quotes) with your start date and `100` with your amount that will serve as both the initial amount and the increment.

If you want a more accounting-accurate version:

`=FV(0,DATEDIF("01/01/2022",TODAY(),"m"),-100,-100)`

`FV` is Future Value (of an investment). Here, `0` is the interest rate, `DATEDIF` will figure out how many complete months have passed as marked from the date in quotes, the first `-100` is the payment amount (which, in accounting, is always negative), and the second `-100` is the initial value contributed on the start date. Using this method would allow you to set different values for the initial value and the monthly increase thereafter.